# Maximizing a rational (quadratic over linear) function over a half-space

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

Recently, I have been trying to solve the following optimization problem:

$$
\begin{array}{cl}
\text{maximize} & \frac{\left(c_1^T x\right)\left(c_2^T x\right)}{d^T x}\\
\text{subject to} & a^Tx\leq b
\end{array}
$$

where $a, c_1, c_2, d \in \Bbb R_{>0}^n$, $b > 0$, and $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n \geq 0$.

---

The Lagrangian of the optimization problem can be written as
$$
L=\frac{\left(c_1^T x\right)\left(c_2^T x\right)}{d^T x}+\theta\left(b-a^Tx\right)+\phi^Tx,
$$
where $\theta\in \mathbb{R}$, $\theta\geq0$, $\phi$ is a $n\times1$ real vector and $\phi\geq0$. Then the KKT conditions are given by
$$
\frac{c_1^Tx}{d^Tx}c_2+\frac{c_2^Tx}{d^Tx}c_1-\frac{c_1^Tx}{d^Tx}\frac{c_2^Tx}{d^Tx}d=a^T\theta-\phi,
$$
$$
\theta\left(b-a^Tx\right)=0,
$$
$$
\phi^Tx=0,
$$
where $\theta\geq0$, $\phi\geq0$, $x\geq0$ and $a^Tx\leq b$.

---

Now I just want to do some relaxation to find an algorithm to obtain a sub-optimal solution. But I still have no clues. Could someone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: For the first question, yes. If you are at point $\mathbf x$ with $\mathbf a^T\mathbf x<b$, you can move to $(1+\epsilon)\mathbf x$ which increases the objective by a factor of $1+\epsilon$ without violating any of the constraints.

Comment: Hi @Rahul, Thank you! It really helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use de Lagrange Teorem and obtain a system with n-equations and n-variables.